# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'LowSD4temp' not found -Dplyr & ggplot. Worked previously

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm very new to R and have looked at the following to try and find a solution:

1. [ggplot2 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007408/ggplot2-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found)
2. [ggplot2 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'd' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949320/ggplot2-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-d-not-found)
3. [ggplot call inside a function: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '...' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368741/ggplot-call-inside-a-function-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object)

I have tried changing aes to aes_string as suggested here: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e3/help/07/12/6372.html. This did not solve the error.

These don't appear to have answered my questions as I'm not using it within a function, or matrix and this code worked previously when my friend was teaching me just two days ago.

Packages: Dplyr & ggplot2 are used and both active. 
Uses a CSV file holding temperature, rainfall and humidity data.

```
# load the data file, hit tab for selections
dar_baseline <- read.csv(file = "Dar_Baseline_Clean.csv",header = TRUE)

#load packages if you get error use install.packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Calculating stats for Temperature
temp.stats.wide <- dar_baseline %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(meantemp=mean(AIR_TEMPERATURE,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                               sdtemp = sd(AIR_TEMPERATURE,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                               mintemp = min(AIR_TEMPERATURE,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                               maxtemp = max(AIR_TEMPERATURE,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                               sd4temp = sdtemp*4,
                                                               HighSD4temp = meantemp-sd4temp,
                                                               LowSD4temp = meantemp+sd4temp) %>% gather(Statisticstemp, Valuetemp, meantemp:LowSD4temp)
```

This section compiles without any issues and creates a correct table in the global environment with all values there.

```
#Plot data - Temperature
ggplot(data = temp.stats.wide,aes(Month, meantemp))+
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = LowSD4temp, ymax = HighSD4temp), fill = "grey70")+
geom_line(size=1.5, col="blue")+
geom_point(data = dar_baseline,aes(Month,AIR_TEMPERATURE))
```

This section throws up the error - meantemp appears to be read fine, and so does HighSD4temp it's just LowSD4temp.

This worked previously on a different PC and provided a correct plot. 
I've checked and had other people check for typos, other friend coders (who are also unfamiliar with R) can't see any obvious reason why it's stopped working / wont work.

temp.stats.wide table looks like this: 
[temp.stats.wide table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUxI.jpg)

Any help would be great.

Comment: What does head(temp.stats.wide) look like?

Comment: @RichardTelford I've added a link to an image of temp.stats.wide table to the question post. Headings are displayed - meantemp, HighSD4temp and LowSD4temp are within the Statisticstemp column.

Comment: Your data is not in a wide format. ggplot expects LowSD4temp to be a column in the data.frame

Comment: @Richard -Ok, I will retry using the spread function. into separate columns. Out of curiosity - How is it able to read meantemp which is also in the same "Statisticstemp" column?

Comment: I suspect it cannot. It wouldn't need that until it got to geom_line